# Google Apps Script: Comparing Arrays for Unique Values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working from the solution provided [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22222518/9311245) to compare two arrays. The example provided returns values found in both arrays to Array1 (`same`) and values only found on one or the other two Array2 (`diff`).

**ISSUE:** When I apply it to my own script, `valuesDATA` returns nothing and `valuesCheckSeeding` returns ALL values from both arrays

**DESIRED RESULT:** I have two arrays that I'd either like to create a third out of, or only select values from the first array, `valuesDATA` which are NOT present in the second, `valuesCheckSeeding`. Using the solution above, I was trying to have all values not found in `valuesCheckSeeding` AND `valuesDATA` pushed to `valuesDATA`.

**SAMPLE OF `valuesDATA`:** "U09 F
Harford FC Hill/Healey - A
MD
CMSA Girls Saturday U09 A/B North
Premier - Top
TID0118"

What am I doing wrong? I tinkered with changing `matchfound==false` and `matchfound=true` in the loop, but that still didn't give me the desired result.

**MOST RELEVANT SNIPPET**

```
var matchfound = false;

for (var i = 0; i < valuesDATA.length; i++) {
  matchfound=false;
    for (var j = 0; j < valuesCheckSeeding.length; j++) {
      if (valuesDATA[i] == valuesCheckSeeding[j]) {
        valuesCheckSeeding.splice(j, 1);
        matchfound=true;
        continue;
        }
        }
          if (matchfound==false) {
            valuesCheckSeeding.push(valuesDATA[i]);
            valuesDATA.splice(i, 1);
            i=i-1;
            }
          }
```

**WORKIG SCRIPT EDITED FROM COMMENTS/ANSWERS BELOW**

```
//UPDATE SEEDING SHEET
function updateSeedingSheet() {

var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");   

//INPUT SHEET INFO
var inputCurrentRow = 4;
var inputCurrentColumn = 20;
var inputNumRows = 1000;
var inputNumColumns =1;

var ssInput = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Wzg2BklQb6sOZzeC0OEvQ7s7gIQ07sXygEtC0CSGOh4');
var sheetDATA = ssInput.getSheetByName('DATAREF');
var rangeDATA = sheetDATA.getRange(inputCurrentRow, inputCurrentColumn, inputNumRows, inputNumColumns);
var valuesDATA = rangeDATA.getValues();


//SEEDING SHEET INFO
var seedingCurrentRow = 4;
var seedingCurrentColumn = 1;
var seedingNumRows = 1000;
var seedingNumColumns = 1;

var ssSeeding = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1DuCHeZ3zba-nHq-7vYTrylncPGqcA1J9jNyW9DaS3mU');
var sheetSeeding = ssSeeding.getSheetByName('Seeding');
var rangeCheckSeeding = sheetSeeding.getRange(4, 102, 1000, 1);
var columnToClear = sheetSeeding.getRange(seedingCurrentRow, seedingCurrentColumn, seedingNumRows, seedingNumColumns);
var valuesCheckSeeding = rangeCheckSeeding.getValues();


//METHOD TO FILTER
valuesCheckSeeding = valuesCheckSeeding.map(function(e){return e[0];}); //flatten this array
var filteredArr = valuesDATA.filter(function(e){
    return !(this.indexOf(e[0])+1);
},valuesCheckSeeding);
Logger.log(filteredArr);
Logger.log(filteredArr.length);

var rangeSeeding = sheetSeeding.getRange(seedingCurrentRow, seedingCurrentColumn, filteredArr.length, seedingNumColumns);

sheetSeeding.getRange('A1').setValue(today);
columnToClear.clearContent();
rangeSeeding.setValues(filteredArr);



/*
//ALTERNATIVE METHOD USING LOOPS
for (var i = 0; i < valuesDATA.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < valuesCheckSeeding.length; j++) {
      if (valuesDATA[i][0] == valuesCheckSeeding[j][0]) {
        valuesDATA.splice(i, 1);
        i--; //account for the splice
        break; //go to next i iteration of loop
          }
       }
     }
          Logger.log("VALUES DATA:" + valuesDATA);
          Logger.log("VALUES CHECK SEEDING: " + valuesCheckSeeding);         

//sheetSeeding.getRange('A1').setValue(today);
//rangeSeeding.clearContent();
//rangeSeeding.setValues(valuesDATA); //INCORRECT RANGE HEIGHT, WAS 71 BUT SHOULD BE 1000 - Is splice affecting this? 

*/

}//END FUNCTION
```

Comment: Don't `splice` an array while iterating over it, else the logic will be quite hard to understand... if you want to split one array into two, better to `push` to two entirely new arrays

Comment: please show an example of  the contents of `valuesDATA` (it's all just primitive values, right? no objects?) knowing `{key: 1} !== {key: 1}` may shed some light if the contents are not simple primitive values

Comment: "U09 F
Harford FC Hill/Healey - A
MD
CMSA Girls Saturday U09 A/B North
Premier - Top
TID0118" is a sample of the content of `valuesDATA` Pulls directly from the spreadsheet. I have two arrays that I'd either like to create a third out of, or only select values from the first array, `valuesDATA` which are not present in the second `valuesCheckSeeding`. I'll update my question to reflect both points.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and review language-agnostic algorithms for comparing sets. Then review comparing a set with an iterable. Then review constructing a set from an iterable.

Comment: (you have to do it the old -fashioned way since Apps Script has no `Set` class yet.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### V8(ES2016 update):

- You can use newer and efficient [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)  class

```js
const array1 = [[1],[2],[3]],
array2 = [[1],[3],[4]],
set = new Set(array2.flat())
console.info(array1.filter(e => !set.has(e[0])))
//expected output [[2]]
```

---

- You're checking a 2D array. You'd need to use `[i][0]` and `[j][0]`
- You can try only splicing `valuesDATA`

Try

```
for (var i = 0; i < valuesDATA.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < valuesCheckSeeding.length; j++) {
      if (valuesDATA[i][0] == valuesCheckSeeding[j][0]) {
        valuesDATA.splice(i, 1);
        i--; //account for the splice
        break; //go to next i iteration of loop
        }
     }
}
Logger.log(valuesDATA);
```

---

Alternatively, try

```
valuesCheckSeeding = valuesCheckSeeding.map(function(e){return e[0];}); //flatten this array
var filteredArr = valuesDATA.filter(function(e){
    return !(this.indexOf(e[0])+1);
},valuesCheckSeeding);
Logger.log(filteredArr);
```

Comment: That worked. When I had done it myself with two loops, it was very slow. I had come across the method described above and it was way faster, so I was trying to build from that and I missed some little things like `[i][0]`. `.map` is new to me and something to look into more. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is old but just wanted to point out that filteredArr is misspelled in Logger.log.

Comment: I noticed the V8 version as well. Super quick. Thanks!