# Checking to see if two arrays are equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to determine whether the first part of two arrays are equal.  The logger shows them as identical but it is still returning FALSE.  Is it not possible to compare arrays in this way?

```
function equality() {
var one = [['Name, Class'],['One', 'Two']];
var two = ['Name, Class'];
Logger.log(one[0]);
Logger.log(two);
 if (one[0]===two) {
  Logger.log('TRUE') 
 }
 else {
 Logger.log('FALSE'); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a possible duplicate of this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209066/how-to-compare-2-arrays-in-app-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just use the equality operator to compare two JavaScript arrays since they are objects. They can be used for null and undefined checks but while checking them against each other they would fail.

One method i mostly use is by stringifying them using JSON.stringify(obj).

In your case it would be something like this :-

```
if(JSON.stringify(one[0]) == JSON.stringify(two))
```

This will give you the result you are hoping for.

Comment: With great powers comes great responsibility

Answer (score 0):

You have to use == operator to equal in this case, and And array need to specify which object

use the code as below

```
function myFunction() {
    var one = [['Name, Class'],['One', 'Two']];
    var two = ['Name, Class'];
    Logger.log(one[0]);
    Logger.log(two);
    if (one[0]==two[0]) {
        Logger.log('TRUE') 
    }
    else {
        Logger.log('FALSE'); 
    }
}
```